# Update Css/Js bundles (Visual Studio Bundler Minifier) from the command line

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, bundling-and-minification

I am in the process of creating automated update scripts for my websites. All websites are built using WebForms in Visual Studio 2017 (Not Core).

What I want to do is run a command line calling the bundlerconfig.json to update bundles for a certain project.

From what I can see there is a way using dotnet bundle, but I think this is just for DotNet Core projects.

Would be good to know either way whether this is possible or not. Thanks in advance.